# Google CSE autocomplete setup

Tags: search

I'm new to using Google search on local website installations.

I have successfully installed the [Google-CSE](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_cse) module and upon searching, results are successfully displayed from Google.

**However, my problem is there are no auto-suggestions when a user begins typing content into the search textfield.**

Can anyone tell me how to configure my Drupal textfield to show auto-suggestions when input is typed, please?

PS:

My Google site index has autocomplete enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was to copy the **scripts/autocomplete.js** folder from Googles' **GSS** module into a custom module, include the autocomplete.js in *mymodule.info* and imitate the few lines of code in GSS.module which implements the autocomplete functionality.

If you ask me, Google left the CSE unfinished.